# What is the best way to create a single PNG image containing multiple PNGs of the same size?

Tags: images, graphics, png

What is the best way to create a single PNG image that contains multiple PNGs of the same size, such as 32x32 and 64x64?

I have a lot of images that I need to include in a single image so I can load them all as just one image.  I only have access to open source tools.  I need a fast/efficient way to do this.  Is such an image called a sprite or a tile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used in reference to images used in websites, combining images like this is referred to as a [CSS sprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS).

You can use the Imagemagick (open source) [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) tool to quickly combine your icons into a big file.

This would make a 5x5 tile single image of everything in the current folder:

```
montage -background transparent -tile 5x5 *.png sprite.png
```

If there are less than 25 images, then blank spaces will be used.  The last file on the command line is the output file.

Imagemagick is a command line tool and so often the fastest and most efficient way to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, montage allows you to tile multiple image, with customized border, padding, number of rows/columns...

Comment: what could a montage command look like to combine icons into a single file?  say all icons in a given directory?  most likely I will want to place them one row by row or column by column.

Comment: I added an example to the answer